# Best Application (or Gadget) Container for python Django SN

Tags: python, django, social-networking, opensocial

I am trying to create a social-network based on python django.
Is anybody know which is the best Application Container (eg. Apache Shindig, Apache Rave) for this?

Thanx.

Comment: Are you looking to build the frontend with python django?

Comment: No. I am already build all the project with python django. (Frontend and backend)

Answer (score 0):

I decided to make it my own way.

So i created an rest api with [tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and i made an "Application Container" using iframe and javascript.

Also, i created an django-app for apps registration which will be uploaded to django-packages soon.